# Angularfire 2 query equalTo object

Tags: typescript, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I am trying to filter data from firebase query based on some labels

My data is structured like this

- projects:

  - projectId:

    - labels:

      - label1: true
      - label2: true

  this.filteredProjects$ = af.database.list(path, {
    query: {
      orderByChild: 'labels',
      equalTo: this.filter$
    }
  });

  filterProjects(filter: string): void {
  this.filter$.next(!filter ? null : {value: true, key: filter});
  }

And i tried to use this firebase feature: 
The Firebase SDK supports an optional key parameter for startAt, endAt, and equalTo when ordering by child, value, or priority. You can specify the key parameter using an object literal that contains the value and the key. For example: startAt: { value: 'some-value', key: 'some-key' }.

But I am getting this error: ERROR Error: Query: First argument passed to startAt(), endAt(), or equalTo() cannot be an object.

Comment: In your database, `labels` an object. You cannot use it when specifying `orderByChild`, as it's not a primitive value.

Comment: So what should I do to be able to query those projects base on one or more labels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do something like this:

```
af.database.list(path, { query: { orderByChild: 'labels/' + label, equalTo: true } });
```

where the `label` variable is the label name I want to query.